# how to display the image in the background dynamically in a chat ..just like whatsapp background wall paper

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i tried hard to display the image in the background for chat box with options using ion-more icon at top-right-side of navigation bar, when clicked on it it shows options as change background and exit.when i clicked on change background it need to be applied on the background of chat box.i cant find the right way.
 then it should take image from gallery in ios or android and in webview it should take image from computer..Any help can be appreciated.??

Comment: Please add your code that you had tried..

Comment: https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/GpCst

Comment: i changed my question read once and see the above link

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you want to put an image in background on selection of menu item. Then it is simple. Override the methods for menu item in your activity and inside switch case set the background image for this activity on selection of this menu item. If you want some clear picture of your question then you need to put your code here or push your code to github.